# How to find permutations in a list then remove them?

Tags: python, permutation

I'm trying to find a permutation of another number in this txt file and then add them to a list:

```
167
168
148
143
289
194 
683
491
```

In this file, the permutations are 491 and 194.

This is my code:

```
numberList = []

file = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    numberList.append(line)
```

Now they're added to `numberList`, how do I remove them (491 and 194) from this list.

Comment: So your question is a little broad if you don't explain what you've tried.

Comment: I simply created a list, read the txt file with open(), then added each line to the list. the next step is to remove the permutations (which are 491, and 419). And i don't know how to do it.

Comment: To get you started, in your "for" loop, change the line to this --> numberList.append(line.strip())

Comment: I am confused too. Are you trying to identify numbers on a list that have permutations of each other, and then remove only those from the list?

Comment: I'm only asking is how to remove the permutations found inside a list, not necessarily 491 and 194, assuming we have 100 numbers and we want to remove the permutations found when adding them to the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, let's do a bit of group theory:

assume you can decompose your numbers x into digits X[i] (removing the `\n` is really trivial, and surely someone else will cover this).

Then we know that, by how the decimal system works,

[image: $$x = \sum_{i=0}^{\log_{10} x} x[i] 10^i$$]

what we need to find is a function y=f(x) that maps x'es that are permutations of the same number to the same y, but x'es that aren't permutations to different y.

we can use the fact that the prime factorization of different numbers is different, and simply find the sum over exponents of a prime that isn't a digit (and larger than the length of the number*digits). This get's easier if we assume less than 9 digits, so we'll do that.

for this example, let's stick to 17 (which further limits our number of digits, but oh well).

[image: $$y= f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{6} 17^{x[i]}$$]

so, now you'd use that function as *comparison key* in a python `set` and be done.

So, very naively (and very untested):

```
class permutation(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
         """
         we'll assume x is an integer
         """
         digits = str(x)
         self.original = x
         self._hash = sum([17**int(digit) for digit in digits])
    def __hash__(self):
         return self._hash
    def __eq__(self,other):
         return self._hash == hash(other)
    def __ne__(self,other):
         return self._hash != hash(other)


permutation_free = set()

file = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    x = int(line)
    permutation_free.add(permutation(x))
print [perm.original for perm in permutation_free]
```

**EDIT:** even tested it.

Comment: Nice, but `numberList` is a bit misleading name for a `set`.

Comment: agreed. have changed, @tobias_k.

Comment: Your answer is awesome. Are you a math professor?  I like your answer for two reasons. Practical use of object orientation to solve the problem, and demonstration of the hash function.

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be two problems: How to read numbers from a text file, and how to detect and filter out the duplicates w.r.t. permutations. For the first, you can use `strip` to get rid of the `\n` and convert to `int` to get actual numbers (although when using `int`, the first step is not really necessary). For filtering out the permutations, I suggest using a dictionary, associating each number with itself in sorted order. Since each permutation will be the same after sorting, this will group numbers that are permutations of each other. If you want to retain the original order, use `collections.OrderedDict`.

```
import collections
numbers = collections.OrderedDict()

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in map(str.strip, f):
        print(line)
        key = ''.join(sorted(line))
        if key not in numbers:
            numbers[key] = []
        numbers[key].append(int(line))
    print(numbers)
```

Afterwards, `numbers` is

```
OrderedDict([('167', [167]), ('168', [168]), ('148', [148]), ('134', [143]), ('289', [289]), ('149', [194, 491]), ('368', [683])])
```

To get the ordered sequence of numbers with no "permutation-duplicates", just get the first element from each of the value-lists:

```
>>> [v[0] for v in numbers.values()]
[167, 168, 148, 143, 289, 194, 683]
```

In case you want to remove *both* the duplicates, you can add an accordant condition:

```
>>> [v[0] for v in numbers.values() if len(v) == 1]
[167, 168, 148, 143, 289, 683]
```

Comment: I like your answer! Much more pythonic than my hash-based/math thing :)

Comment: just one note: instead of  a string `key = ''.join(sorted(line))`, you could just use `key=tuple(sorted(line))`, because tuples are hashables, too.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I thought about using tuples, too, but I think that a) strings look nicer, and b) a tuple of three one-char-strings would probably (?) take up more memory than one three-char-string.

Comment: hm, yes, a tuple would have at least a length + 3* size_t data; don't think that'll ever be relevant, though :D however, if you think in that direction: `int(''.join(sorted(line)))` would definitely have even less overhead, memory-wise (but of course you'd lose the ability to tell 1400 from 41)

Comment: Nice use of ordered dictionary. I noticed that your no_dupes assignment removes the duplicates effectively. I noticed that '194' is still in the list which should also be removed. How would you remove both permutations instead of just the dupes?

Comment: @Joe Should it? I was not sure from the question. Anyway, added a way to remove both numbers.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can do this in just 3 additional lines of code:

1. Sort each item in the list so that permutations will match
2. Check each item on the list to see where there are permutations, and create a list of those indices
3. Create the new list do not add the indices that were identified as permutations:

So the whole program will look like this:

```
numberList = []

file = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    numberList.append(line.strip())

x = [sorted(y) for y in numberList]
indices = [i for i, item in enumerate(x) if x.count(item) > 1]
numberList = [item for i, item in enumerate(numberList) if i not in indices]
```

Results:

```
>>> numberList
[167, 168, 148, 143, 289, 683]
>>>
```